# How to treeify Python dicts?

Tags: python, dictionary, tree

I'm building a telegram bot, and would like to convert the json responses such as the one below which I turn into a dictionary:

```
{
  "message_id": 445793,
  "from": {
   "id": 106596774,
   "is_bot": false,
   "first_name": "Komron",
   "last_name": "Aripov",
   "username": "tgcode",
   "language_code": "en"
  },
  "chat": {
   "id": 106596774,
   "first_name": "Komron",
   "last_name": "Aripov",
   "username": "tgcode",
   "type": "private"
  },
  "date": 1549380586,
  "text": "ayye"
}
```

into a neat little tree, such as this:

```
Message
 ├ message_id: 445793
 ├ from
 ┊  ├ id: 106596774
 ┊  ├ is_bot: false
 ┊  ├ first_name: Komron
 ┊  ├ last_name: Aripov
 ┊  ├ username: tgcode
 ┊  └ language_code: en
 ├ chat
 ┊  ├ id: 106596774
 ┊  ├ first_name: Komron
 ┊  ├ last_name: Aripov
 ┊  ├ username: tgcode
 ┊  └ type: private
 ├ date: 1549290736
 └ text: ayye
```

I've tried using the [treelib](https://github.com/caesar0301/treelib/) library for python, but it is doesn't offer a method for their class to convert a json into the needed formatted text. It also seems a little too complex for my use case.

There's a library for my use case on [github](https://github.com/notatestuser/treeify), but it's in javascript (can't understand it to reverse engineer)

Comment: Could you add a sample input of the dictionary, for example, the one matching that output?

Comment: did you tried [pyyaml](https://pyyaml.org/)? Your tree looks very like yaml output

Comment: Closest you would get is `json.dumps(your_dict, indent=4)`. And if you need sorted keys just add `sorted=True` to the call.

Comment: @DanielMesejo Please take a look again. I've added it.

Comment: For future readers: See my answer at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75719504/21305238).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seemed like fun so I gave it a go:

```
def custom_display(input, depth = 0):
    if depth == 0:
        output_string = "Message\n"
    else:
        output_string = ""
    if type(input) is dict:
        final_index = len(input)-1
        current_index = 0
        for key, value in input.items():
            for indent in range(0, depth):
                output_string += "  ┊ "
            if current_index == final_index:
                output_string += "  └ "
            else:
                output_string += "  ├ "
                current_index += 1
            if type(value) is dict:
                output_string += key + '\n' + custom_display(value, depth + 1)
            else:
                output_string += key + ": " + custom_display(value, depth+1) + '\n'
    else:
        output_string = str(input)

    return output_string
```

Using,

```
dict_input = {
  "message_id": 445793,
  "from": {
   "id": 106596774,
   "is_bot": False,
   "first_name": "Komron",
   "last_name": "Aripov",
   "username": "tgcode",
   "language_code": "en"
  },
  "chat": {
   "id": 106596774,
   "first_name": "Komron",
   "last_name": "Aripov",
   "username": "tgcode",
   "type": "private"
  },
  "date": 1549380586,
  "text": "ayye"
}

print(custom_display(dict_input))
```

Gives an output of:

```
Message
  ├ message_id: 445793
  ├ from
  ┊   ├ id: 106596774
  ┊   ├ is_bot: False
  ┊   ├ first_name: Komron
  ┊   ├ last_name: Aripov
  ┊   ├ username: tgcode
  ┊   └ language_code: en
  ├ chat
  ┊   ├ id: 106596774
  ┊   ├ first_name: Komron
  ┊   ├ last_name: Aripov
  ┊   ├ username: tgcode
  ┊   └ type: private
  ├ date: 1549380586
  └ text: ayye
```

Comment: This handles `{ "deeply": { "nested": { "dict": {} } } }` incorrectly.