# Printing Python dictionnary as a tree

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion, tree

I would like to treeify a dictionary in Python.
I found this thread ([How to treeify Python dicts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54537779/how-to-treeify-python-dicts)) where the solution given is almost what I need.

This is the original code :

```
def custom_display(input, depth = 0):
    if depth == 0:
        output_string = "Message\n"
    else:
        output_string = ""
    if type(input) is dict:
        final_index = len(input)-1
        current_index = 0
        for key, value in input.items():
            for indent in range(0, depth):
                output_string += "  ┊ "
            if current_index == final_index:
                output_string += "  └ "
            else:
                output_string += "  ├ "
                current_index += 1
            if type(value) is dict:
                output_string += key + '\n' + custom_display(value, depth + 1)
            else:
                output_string += key + ": " + custom_display(value, depth+1) + '\n'
    else:
        output_string = str(input)

    return output_string
```

Here's its output :

```
Message
  ├ message_id: 445793
  ├ from
  ┊   ├ id: 106596774
  ┊   ├ is_bot: False
  ┊   ├ first_name: Komron
  ┊   ├ last_name: Aripov
  ┊   ├ username: tgcode
  ┊   └ language_code:
  ┊      └ code_specs: [elt1, elt2, elt3]
  ├ chat
  ┊   ├ id: 106596774
  ┊   ├ first_name: Komron
  ┊   ├ last_name: Aripov
  ┊   ├ username: tgcode
  ┊   ├ attributes: [elt1, elt2, elt3]
  ┊   └ type: private
  ├ date: 1549380586
  └ list: [elt1, elt2, elt3, elt4]
```

Here's what I would like to achieve :

```
Message
  ├ message_id: 445793
  ├ from
  ┊   ├ id: 106596774
  ┊   ├ is_bot: False
  ┊   ├ first_name: Komron
  ┊   ├ last_name: Aripov
  ┊   ├ username: tgcode
  ┊   └ language_code
  ┊       ├ code_specs:
  ┊       ┊   ├ elt1
  ┊       ┊   ├ elt2
  ┊       ┊   └ elt3
  ┊       ├ item: value
  ┊       └ code: utf
  ├ chat
  ┊   ├ id: 106596774
  ┊   ├ first_name: Komron
  ┊   ├ last_name: Aripov
  ┊   ├ username: tgcode
  ┊   ├ attributes:
  ┊   ┊   ├ elt1
  ┊   ┊   ├ elt2
  ┊   ┊   ├ elt3
  ┊   ┊   └ elt4
  ┊   └ type: private
  ├ date: 1549380586
  └ list:
      ├ elt1
      ├ elt2
      ├ elt3
      └ elt4
```

EDIT: Also as @InSync noted, the original code does not properly render deep nested dictionnaries.

Any idea ?
Best regards

Comment: I belive this is not how questions work. Please share you code, its output and identify problems with it. [How to create minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: That's not *your* code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike the original answer, the following solution handles deeply nested dicts/lists correctly. It also converts each value to its representation string (`!r`) due to potential problems with empty strings. If a value of type dict or list is encountered, the property name will be output as `<index n>`.

```py
def custom_display(data, indents = None, text = None):
    if indents is None:
        indents = []
    
    if text is None:
        text = ['Message']
    
    data_is_dict = isinstance(data, dict)
    iterator = data.items() if data_is_dict else data
    
    for index, item in enumerate(iterator):
        if data_is_dict:
            key, value = item
        else:
            key, value = index, item
        
        not_last = index + 1 != len(data)
        
        indent_string = ''.join('  ┊ ' if depth else ' ' * 4 for depth in indents)
        indent_string += f'  {"├" if not_last else "└"} '
        
        if isinstance(value, (dict, list)):
            if isinstance(data, list):
                text.append(f'{indent_string}<index {key}>')
            else:
                text.append(f'{indent_string}{key!r}')
            
            custom_display(value, [*indents, not_last], text)
        
        elif isinstance(data, list):
            text.append(f'{indent_string}{value!r}')
        
        else:
            text.append(f'{indent_string}{key!r}: {value!r}')
    
    return '\n'.join(text)
```

Try it:

```py
dict_input = {
    "array": [1, 2, 3, 'foo', 'bar', 'baz'],
    "deeply": {
        "nested": {
            "object": {},
            "array": [1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b']
        }
    },
    "int": 42,
    "float": 42.24,
    "string": "foobar",
    "emptyString": "",
    "booleanTrue": True,
    "booleanFalse": False,
    "null": None,
    "arrayContainingObjects": [
        { "id": 0, "text": 'foo' },
        { "id": 1, "text": 'bar' },
        { "id": 2, "text": 'baz' },
        'notAnObject',
        [1, 2, 3],
        'notAnArray'
    ]
}

print(custom_display(dict_input))
```

outputs:

```
Message
  ├ 'array'
  ┊   ├ 1
  ┊   ├ 2
  ┊   ├ 3
  ┊   ├ 'foo'
  ┊   ├ 'bar'
  ┊   └ 'baz'
  ├ 'deeply'
  ┊   └ 'nested'
  ┊       ├ 'object'
  ┊       └ 'array'
  ┊           ├ 1
  ┊           ├ 2
  ┊           ├ 3
  ┊           ├ 'a'
  ┊           └ 'b'
  ├ 'int': 42
  ├ 'float': 42.24
  ├ 'string': 'foobar'
  ├ 'emptyString': ''
  ├ 'booleanTrue': True
  ├ 'booleanFalse': False
  ├ 'null': None
  └ 'arrayContainingObjects'
      ├ <index 0>
      ┊   ├ 'id': 0
      ┊   └ 'text': 'foo'
      ├ <index 1>
      ┊   ├ 'id': 1
      ┊   └ 'text': 'bar'
      ├ <index 2>
      ┊   ├ 'id': 2
      ┊   └ 'text': 'baz'
      ├ 'notAnObject'
      ├ <index 4>
      ┊   ├ 1
      ┊   ├ 2
      ┊   └ 3
      └ 'notAnArray'
```

Comment: Brilliant ! The code works perfectly even with deep nested dicts and arrays of dicts ! also the code is fast to my eyes.
Thank you very much ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I modified the code a little bit and here it is. I just copied the first section which is for printing *dictionary* and modified it so that it will ignore the *key* and just print the list. Check to see if it works.

```py
def custom_display(input, depth = 0):
    if depth == 0:
        output_string = "Message\n"
    else:
        output_string = ""
    if type(input) is dict:
        final_index = len(input)-1
        current_index = 0
        for key, value in input.items():
            for indent in range(0, depth):
                output_string += "  ┊ "
            if current_index == final_index:
                output_string += "  └ "
            else:
                output_string += "  ├ "
                current_index += 1
            if type(value) is dict:
                output_string += str(key) + '\n' + custom_display(value, depth + 1)
            else:
                output_string += str(key) + ": " + custom_display(value, depth+1) + '\n'

    elif type(input) is list:
        final_index = len(input)-1
        current_index = 0
        for value in input:
            for indent in range(0, depth):
                output_string += "  ┊ "
            if current_index == final_index:
                output_string += "  └ "
            else:
                output_string += "  ├ "
                current_index += 1
            if type(value) is dict:
                output_string += custom_display(value, depth + 1)
            else:
                output_string += custom_display(value, depth+1) + '\n'

    
    else:
        output_string = str(input)

    return output_string
```

Comment: See [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54537779#comment133576789_54538128) at the original answer. Also, this answer isn't correct: a line break should be added before the first element of a list.